# How can I split the data based on time in netcdf through SciSpark?

Tags: scala, netcdf

```
val data = RDD[SciTensor]
data.map(y => {
val time = y("time")}
```

How we get the units of time and precip long name in SciSpark ? 
below showing ncdump results :

```
time:units = "hours since 1800-01-01 00:00:0.0".
float precip(time, lat, lon) ;
precip:long_name = "Average Monthly Rate of Precipitation"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking the question.
SciSpark is working towards preserving units.

To answer your original question about splitting by time.
Looking at your variable you can definitely split by time, if the time dimension is greater than 1. Otherwise, you don't really need to.

The precip variable array has dimensions time, lat, and lon.

If you want to split by each time epoch you can access the sub-array in each time index like so :

```
val array = y("time")()
val time1 = array(0)
val time2 = array(1)
val time3 = array(2)
etc.
```

If you want to extract the sub-arrays in each time dimension and have the RDD be a collection of these sub-arrays you can do that like so :

```
data.map(y => {
val timeArray = y("time")()
val timeLength = timeArray.shape(0)
(0 until timeLength).map(i => timeArray(i))
})
```

This will give you an RDD of type RDD[Iterable[AbstractTensor]]

The Iterable[AbstractTensor] corresponds to the original array which you have split by time.

You can go further and call a flatMap to get an RDD of type RDD[AbstractTensor] like so :

```
data.flatMap(y => {
val timeArray = y("time")()
val timeLength = timeArray.shape(0)
(0 until timeLength).map(i => timeArray(i))
})
```

Make sure you are using the latest version of SciSpark.
Some of the indexing functionality is recently introduced.